# How to use variable name in WMI service query in VBS

Tags: vbscript, wmi, wmi-query

How can I put the current year in CURRENT_YEAR so the folder I am monitoring is `P:\\\\Folder1\\\\Folder2\\\\Folder3\\\\2020`

I have the following code in a vbs file:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE _
Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and TargetInstance.GroupComponent= 'Win32_Directory.Name=""P:\\\\Folder1\\\\Folder2\\\\Folder3\\\\CURRENT_YEAR""'")
Do
'code to execute if file in folder found
Loop
```

Comment: What's with the weird folder path?, it should be <drive>:\folder\subfolder\. Only need \\ when escaping the path separators in a WMI string.

Comment: @Lankymart It is a network drive and four slashes is the only way it works.

Comment: So "P:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\"& CURRENT_YEAR doesn’t work? It [certainly should](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31324573/692942). Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31568922/692942).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vbscript you can get the year like this :

---

```
CURRENT_YEAR=Year(Now)
MsgBox CURRENT_YEAR
MsgBox "P:\\\\Folder1\\\\Folder2\\\\Folder3\\\\"& CURRENT_YEAR &""
```

---

```
CURRENT_YEAR=Year(Now)
sPath = "F:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\"& CURRENT_YEAR
sDrive = split(sPath,":")(0)
sFolders1 = split(sPath,":")(1)
sFolders = REPLACE(sFolders1, "\", "\\\\")
TargetFolder = DblQuote(sDrive & ":" & sFolders)

wscript.echo sPath
wscript.echo TargetFolder

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 2 Where " _
    & "Targetinstance Isa 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and " _
    & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " _
    & "'Win32_Directory.Name="& TargetFolder &"'")

' The loop
Do
    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    Wscript.Echo objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent
Loop
'-------------------------------------------------------------
Function DblQuote(str)
    DblQuote = chr(34) & str & chr(34)
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Yes can you help me with how to integrate it into the quotes. It is really confusing with the double and single quotes.

Comment: @kindofhungry How is it confusing? Strings in VBScript start and end with a double quote (`"`) while WMI query strings start and end with a single quote (`'`). When you want to use a literal double quote in a string in VBScript you have to double it (you will likely need this when dealing with file paths with spaces in) like this `"""test"""` would be output as a `"test"`. Use of `Chr(34)` is just a work around for people who don't like using `""` to escape strings and completely unnecessary and imo less readable.

Comment: @kindofhungry what maybe confusing is how the strings break across lines using `& _`. What is happening here is `&` is used to concatenate strings together and `_` tells VBScript to continue the command on the next line, it is also known as the Line Continuation Character. **Hackoo doesn’t tend to explain the code they post unfortunately.**