# How to monitor folder for file that begins with variable string in VBS

Tags: vbscript, wmi, wmi-query

I have the following code in a VBS file. How can I monitor files in `Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\2020` for files that begin with a specific string

```
    file_starts_with = "abc" & Year(Now()) & " " & Month(Now()) & " " & Day(Now())
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 _
     WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and TargetInstance.GroupComponent= 'Win32_Directory.Name=""P:\\\\Folder1\\\\Folder2\\\\Folder3\\\\2020""'")
     Do
         Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
         'more code here
     Loop
```

Comment: @Hackoo Kind of. Is there a TargetInstance for file name and how to make it so it is a "starts with"?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [WMI and File System Monitoring](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/42212/wmi-and-file-system-monitoring) , You can write something like that :

---

```
CURRENT_YEAR=Year(Now)
sPath = "F:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\"& CURRENT_YEAR
sDrive = split(sPath,":")(0)
sFolders1 = split(sPath,":")(1)
sFolders = REPLACE(sFolders1, "\", "\\\\")
TargetFolder = DblQuote(sDrive & ":" & sFolders)

wscript.echo sPath
wscript.echo TargetFolder

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 2 Where " _
    & "Targetinstance Isa 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and " _
    & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " _
    & "'Win32_Directory.Name="& TargetFolder &"'")

' The loop
Do
    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    Wscript.Echo objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent
Loop
'-------------------------------------------------------------
Function DblQuote(str)
    DblQuote = chr(34) & str & chr(34)
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I think this was mean to answer my other question :)

Comment: If you post this answer there, I will check it because it works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64616381/how-to-use-variable-name-in-wmi-service-query-in-vbs

Comment: I did not downvote! Your answer worked for me for my other problem! I think someone else downvoted because it did not answer the file name starts with part

Comment: So if it worked why you don't accept it as anwser ?

Comment: I accepted on my other post, but I still have the question here: How can I monitor files in `Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\2020` for files that begin with a specific string